# Getting input report in pywinusb

Tags: pywinusb

I am using pywinusb to send/get data from Custom HID device. I can successfully send data but cant get it. Any suggestions? I tried to debug using Microsoft Message Analyzer and can see the data there but not in the script. Product/Vendor Ids, report id etc are correct.

Here the code,

```
from pywinusb import hid
from time import sleep

devicefilter = hid.HidDeviceFilter(vendor_id=0x0483, product_id=0x572A)

devices = devicefilter.get_devices()
print ("devices:", devices)

hid_device = devices[0]
print ("hid_device:", hid_device)

hid_device.open()
out_report = hid_device.find_output_reports()
in_report = hid_device.find_input_reports()
print("out_report:", out_report)
print("out_report[0]:",out_report[0])
print("in_report:", in_report)
print("in_report[0]:",in_report[0])

txBuffer = [0x55] * 64
txBuffer[0] = 0x01 # Report ID
rxBuffer = [0x00] * 64
rxBuffer[0] = 0x02 # Report ID
print(txBuffer)
print(rxBuffer)
out_report[0].set_raw_data(txBuffer)
in_report[0].set_raw_data(rxBuffer)
while 1:
    out_report[0].send()
    rxBuffer = in_report[0].get()
    print("rxBuffer:", rxBuffer)
    sleep(1)
hid_device.close()
```

Comment: I suggest to insert a pause between send() and read().
In addition it is not needed to set the raw data of the in_report(), because this will be overwritten with the received data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this my self but I have a similar sounding application Here is what I do. I don't explicitly create an input report but rather attach an input report handler to the usb receive buffer.

```
import pywinusb.hid as hid

# handler called when a report is received
def rx_handler(data):
    print 'recv: ', data

def scan_hiddevice():
    """ Scans for and returns the HID device. """
    devices = hid.HidDeviceFilter( vendor_id = vendor_id).get_devices()
    if not devices:
        print "scan_hiddevice: No device connected."
        return None
    else:
        device = devices[0]
        #print("scan_hiddevice: found %s", device )
        return device    
    return None

def setup_hiddevice():
    """Creates a new HID device, opens it and attaches a receive data handler"""
    hid_device = scan_hiddevice()
    hid_device.open()
    hid_device.set_raw_data_handler(rx_handler)
    return hid_device

def main(verbose=True):
    hid_device = setup_hiddevice()

    while (True):
        #wait for data
```

I hope this can be of some use.